# How can I get both monitors to look the same?

Tags: color-management, white-balance, color-correction, color-spaces, display-calibration

I have used `Acer V247Ybip`  for about a year and decided to buy `Acer V247bi` to use for second monitor, which is basically the same monitor, but without the Display Port.

The problem is that basically I have 2 of the same monitors, but the colors differ quite a bit, the new one  has more blackish blacks and the white is more red, compared to the older.
Both monitors are using the same settings for: Contrast, Brightness, Gamma, Profile Mode(which is named "cool"), but the colors differ.

The only different thing is that I use Display Port cable for the older one and HDMI 2.0 for the new one.

Here is reference to the models specifications: https://www.displayspecifications.com/en/comparison/2f87680d4

Some pictures, the new one is on the left:[image]

[image]

This problem is making me crazy and I think to buy monitor calibrator such as Spyder5 Pro, but I am not sure if it's worth the purchase. Can anybody tell me if at least this gadget lasts long time? If I can use it for at least 4-5 years, this will make this purchase more valuable.

And I want to ask one more thing, I think that one monitor is set with different color temps, than the other, like 50k and 65k. If some of you know a way to set this color temps manually and not just use the build in display modes, maybe I can fix the problem even without buying calibrator.

Comment: Welcome to Photo SE! Unfortunately, questions that begin with "Is it worth it..." tend to be closed here as "opinion based." Stack Exchange is set up to be a question and answer format for things that have a definitive answer. "Is it worth it..." can not have a definitive answer as for some people the answer would be "yes" and for other people the answer will be "no." Rather than asking "is it worth it..." perhaps you could edit your question to something like, "How can I get both monitors to look the same?" Then each reader can look at proposed solutions and decide for themselves.

Comment: Hi @MichaelC, thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Comment: Are the two monitors properly identified on the PC (make/model)? Some connection cables make that possible, some don't, so it could be that your PC is using default settings for one. If both displays support both cables try switching cables.

Comment: @xenoid It does identifies them (I can see their specs in the monitor info in windows), and I also tried with varied of cables on both monitors 2xVGA, 2xHDMI, HDMI on 1 VGA on other, etc. Still the screen color differs.

Comment: I've found Acer monitors to vary wildly straight out of the box. Once calibrated they are good monitors, though. When they are new the brightness and contrast needs to be pulled WAY back, and sometimes the individual color channels, too. That's good, though. As a monitor ages it gets dimmer. Each time you calibrate it (I do mine about every 2-4 weeks) it will change slightly. Over time, you'll notice that you are increasing the brightness until you have to use full brightness to reach your target. I calibrate mine to 120 cd/m².

Comment: My last primary monitor, a Dell, lasted about six years before it can no longer be turned up bright enough to reach 120 cd/m². It still looks good, but I no longer use it for color critical work. The Dell was nowhere near as bright when new as my newest Acer is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not surprising at all that your two monitors display differently. At work, I have two monitors from the same batch (!) and they are almost as different as yours. (Incidentally, also Acer, but this applies to most consumer displays).

If you *had* Spyder5, the problem would be solved. With [a little workaround](https://www.photoshopcs.com/cheap_dual_monitor_calibration_spyder.html), or by using [free 3rd-party software](https://www.argyllcms.com/), you can match two monitors even with the cheaper Express version. (Express has practically the same hardware; only software differs).

Remember that a colour calibrator is much more than a monitor-matching tool. You will have an *absolute* reference to colours, and can have confidence in your output.

Yes, it lasts quite long. I had Spyder3 for some 10 years, then got new Spyder5 and cross-checked them, and the results matched. This Spyder5 is now 4 or 5 yo and still seems to be fine.

You can probably borrow one if you only want to match your monitors once. But remember that monitors change over time, particularly in the first half-year of use.

Now, without a calibrator, you are down to fiddling with monitor settings and comparing them by eye side by side. If, after equalising brightness, the 'standard' settings don't match, you'll likely need to get to the individual R-G-B gain adjustments (most standalone monitors have them in some 'custom' or 'advanced' colour mode) and change them until they match. Use your 'better' monitor as a guide, but you may need to adjust it too. You'll need a test image with several colours (and greys) at different levels: shadows, midtones, highlights.

Nearly all consumer LCD monitors are too bluish in their native settings (with 100% R-G-B gains). My work monitor (one of) has 94% R - 100% G - 69% B (suggested by Spyder), and I find this level of gains rather typical for consumer monitors (when targeting 6500K). But without a calibrator, you have nothing to verify it with. And still, with only RGB gains, you may not be able to match all levels: say, if you match whites, the middle grey may have a tint. But it will be much better than what you have now.